# Microsoft Power BI drillthrough from one table report to another (each uses different datasets)

Tags: dataset, relationship, powerbi, drilldown, drillthrough

I am fairly new to Power BI reporting. My question may be somewhat pedestrian. I have this situation below:

I have a Category report in a table in Page 1 of Power BI desktop; this Category report is developed from Categories dataset.

I have a Product report in a table in Page 2 of Power BI desktop; this Product report is developed from Products dataset.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The Category dataset and Product dataset have a M:1 relationship using CategoryID column, from the Products table to the Categories table (see diagram attached).

[image]

I set the drill through properties in  Page 2,  using the CategoryID column (see diagram).

[image]

However, when I go to Page 1, and right click a CategoryID value (say 1), I am not able to see the Drillthrough option to navigate from Page 1 to Page 2 !

[image]

[image]

Am I wrong somewhere ? Even after watching many videos and reading many forums, I have been struggling with this for over a day. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following:

In the Page 2 (Products detail report), I changed the drill-through filter from CategoryID (Products table) (this was set originally) to **CategoryID (Categories table).**

Now, when I open Page 1 (Categories summary report), and right click the CategoryID, I am able to see the drill-through option. It takes me to Page 2 Products detail report, only with the filtered Categories.

It was a matter of changing the table (for the same column - CategoryID).

Thanks for the solution